# Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I host our website in our private data center (Not Azure).  Today we lost the network for about an hour.  Which meant users got a page not found error.

Our DNS is in Azure.  I looking for a resource that can manage the redirection of our IP address to a different web site if our primary website is down.  I think Application gateway can do this but as I have never set it up so I don't know.

Can anyone help out with advice on how to do this.

I can't move the website to Azure so this is not an option.

Any help would be great.

cheers
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Application gateway cannot do that, what you are looking for is [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview). It is capable of probing endpoints and getting users to the working ones.

> Microsoft Azure Traffic Manager allows you to control the distribution
>   of user traffic for service endpoints in different datacenters.
>   Service endpoints supported by Traffic Manager include Azure VMs, Web
>   Apps, and cloud services. You can also use Traffic Manager with
>   external, non-Azure endpoints.
>
> Traffic Manager uses the Domain Name System (DNS) to direct client
>   requests to the most appropriate endpoint based on a traffic-routing
>   method and the health of the endpoints. Traffic Manager provides a
>   range of traffic-routing methods and endpoint monitoring options to
>   suit different application needs and automatic failover models.
>   Traffic Manager is resilient to failure, including the failure of an
>   entire Azure region.